# Mi Band 6 BLE - How to access SPo2 (Blood Oxygen saturation)

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm new to this whole world of Bluetooth Low Energy, and I'm trying to make a monitoring app that shows Heart Rate, SPo2, angle and position (motion) from the band. I'm doing it on Android Studio and Java. I've been able to make the app scan for Bluetooth devices, and access the Heart Rate Service and Characteristic.

But I'm having a rought time figuring out how to access SPo2 and motion (if they're even readable) on the Mi Band 6.

I'm using the base [BluetoothLeGatt project](https://github.com/dustedrob/BluetoothLeGatt),to understand how services, characteristics and descriptors work, as well as how the data is sent and received by the app and how to process it to be more readable (bytes to numbers, strings, etc). But I can't manage to find this services I'm looking for.

Is there a way to ask for a SPo2 measurement? Or read previous measurement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just from personal experience with other BLE devices, I believe that this is not possible. SPo2 and motion are only available in the dedicated app provided by the manufacturer. There most likely is no single characteristic containing the information you want. A Smartband/Smartwatch is not a easily accessible sensor array

Comment: Did you end up having any success with this?